# Download file with ajax() POST request via Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

I try to download a file. The action is triggered by `ajax()` POST request. The request sends *data* in JSON format to the controller. The controller generates the file (bytes) and sends it back.

*JavaScript:*

```
function getLicenseFile() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/licenses/rest/downloadLicenseFile',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        data: ko.mapping.toJSON(licenseModel),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("in sucess")
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            console.log("in error")
        } 
    });
}
```

*Controller:*

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/licenses/rest/downloadLicenseFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public void createLicenseFile(@Valid @RequestBody License license, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    logger.debug("Contoller License in: "+ license);

    byte[] licensedata = licenseEncodeDefaultService.createLicenseFile(license);
    logger.debug("licenseData: " + new String(licensedata));

    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + license.getCustomer() + ".license\"");
    response.getOutputStream().write(licensedata);
    response.flushBuffer();
}
```

### *Problem*

- The Browser should open a download box, but it does not happen
- The response is handled in the error: section of ajax function (but the HTTP Status is `OK`)

So what do I do wrong or what is the proper way to do this?

Comment: You're setting `dataType: 'json'` but sending some kind of license file? Also I don't think you can use ajax to download a file.

Comment: trying to download a file to be saved to local directory with ajax can't be done, and is a lot more code than simply directing to the file url itself

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613526/php-file-download-using-post-data-via-jquery-ajax?rq=1 could well help

Comment: **Found a working solution:**
What is the proper way to communicate. Shall I answer my own question ???

Comment: @Musa Of course you are right. I miss that dataType is for return value.

Comment: It's ok to answer your own question.

Comment: @derlinuxer Could you please share the Working Solution you found? I have exactly the same issue...

Comment: @will824 Sorry for delay. You can now find me solution in answers.

Answer (score 17):

Just send a URL of file in response and then "visit" it in your `success` callback.

```
function getLicenseFile() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/licenses/rest/downloadLicenseFile',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        data: ko.mapping.toJSON(licenseModel),
        success: function (data) {
            window.open(data.fileUrl);
            // or window.location.href = data.fileUrl;
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log("in error");
        } 
    });
}
```

`data.fileUrl` should be set in response by server to say client where to get the file.

So your server will send a response with JSON like

```
{
    "fileUrl": "http://mysite.com/files/0123456789"
}
```

Comment: hmm, normally I don't want to save the file in file system on server side and also I want have a clean download URL. Just generate in Memory and send back the bytes. But my be I've to do it really with two controller methods. First method generate the file (save to server FS) and return the file name in JSON Format. And second method send the file data. So I can prevent to have a clean download path. I'll check that out.

Comment: window.open(data.fileUrl); does not work in an asynchronous environment. window.location.href = data.fileUrl; works perfectly!

Answer (score 8):

*@will824* As you ask I'll post my own solution.

I used a workaround in controller and save the file temporarily in the files ystem (`/tmp`). I split up the function in 2 steps. Creating and downloading.
This is not very nice but good enough for me.

*Controller* (creates a file, will be saved on the server file system):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/licenses/rest", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public String createLicenseFile(@Valid @RequestBody License license) throws Exception {

    // create encrypted license file and send the name back to view
    String fileName =  licenseEncodeDefaultService.createLicenseFile(license);
    return fileName;

}
```

*Controller* (downloads a file):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/licenses/downloadFile/{file}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void downloadLicenseFile(@PathVariable("file") String file, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    // create full filename and get input stream
    File licenseFile = new File ("/tmp/" + file);
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(licenseFile);

    // set file as attached data and copy file data to response output stream
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file + ".license\"");
    FileCopyUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());

    // delete file on server file system
    licenseFile.delete();

    // close stream and return to view
    response.flushBuffer();
}
```

*JavaScript:*

```
function getLicenseFile() {
    //console.log(ko.mapping.toJSON(licenseModel));
    $.ajax({
        type : 'PUT',
        url : '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/licenses/rest',
        dataType : 'text',
        contentType : 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        data : ko.mapping.toJSON(licenseModel),
        success : function(data) {
            window.location.href = '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/licenses/downloadFile/'
                    + data;
        },
        error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            // error handling
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I do agree this makes a 1 step simple process to go 2 times to server, but your solution is more or less similar to the one I planned to implement, nevertheless I was not allowed to go 2 times to server, so just had to go with the 1 step call by using an invisible form with an iframe and accept the risk that if there is some error the user will never know what happened.

Answer (score 4):

If you want download file without change URL, you can call `form.submit()` *programmatically* instead of using AJAX.

*JavaScript:*

```
function downloadFileUsingForm(url) { 
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.method = "post";
    form.action = url;
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
    document.body.removeChild(form);
}
downloadFileUsingForm("/YourController/DownloadFile");
```

*Controller:*

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DownloadFile()
{
    string content = "Some Values";
    byte[] bytes = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
    return File(bytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "file.txt");
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer I have found for the case I am working on.

Comment: _As a side note:_ the question was about Spring MVC (hence Java), but  your controller example is in **C#** and **.NET**

Comment: Submitting a form will not send a JSON, which was required in the questions, so this answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments said you can't do it with an ajax call, but you can do it with plain Javascript.

```
function getLicenseFile() {
    var downloadUrl = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/licenses/rest/downloadLicenseFile";
    // (optionally) provide the user with a message that the download is starting
    window.location.href = downloadUrl;
}
```

Note the use of `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`, which is preferred over `<%=request.getContextPath()%>`.

Comment: Thanks, but the file isn't already on server side. It will created dynamic with given JSON Data by post request. No JSON Data no file to download.

Comment: Yep I missed that. In that case I'd use a standard form POST then. No JavaScript is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is not going to help you  try with hidden form approach

```
<form action='../servletname' method='POST' id='formid'>
                <input type='hidden' value='' name='name' id='id'/>
                <input type='hidden' value=' ' name='name'  id='id' />
            </form>
```

pass you json through form field
on click of of your download button  submit form

$('#formid').submit();

then in server side

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=filnemae.fileformat");

 ServletOutputStream out = res.getOutputStream();
```

write on ouput stream then close or flush

if you are sending large data through post **update postsize in server.xml**