# Spring mvc - Made post request and stay on the same page in case of error

Tags: java, excel, spring, spring-mvc

I need to create an action in my controller to generate excel file. The problem is that if error occurs, the page is changed but I would like to stay on the same page showing that error.

I have this action in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/excel", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String generateExcel(HttpServletResponse response, Model model)
```

I would like to stay on the same page in case of error:

```
    if(noError){
      // generate Excel
      response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename= "excel.xls");
      response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
      //...
      return "";
    } else {
      // stay on the same page and show error
      // TODO
      return ?;
    }
```

My excel generation is working fine but when error occurs, the new page is shown. I can't make ajax call to generate excel.
Can someone help me?

Comment: See the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519058/download-file-with-ajax-post-request-via-spring-mvc

Comment: return "redirect:/your_page_with_error";

Comment: You're looking for a combination of `@ResponseBody` annotation and callback function in javascript.

Comment: @EgorZhuk The question is very similar but I would like to aviod double call to controller.

Comment: @MicD I'm trying to preserve the original page in case of error.

Comment: @peech Yes but I can't use callback function with no ajax call (I'm changing page so no callback)

Comment: wait, what? do you want to preserve or change the original page?

Comment: I would like to preserve it but unfortunately you can't download a file with ajax call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use GetMapping:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/download")
public void download(
        @RequestParam("fileReference") String fileReference, // sample param
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    Assert.hasText(fileReference);
    try {
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myfilename.pdf");
        response.setContentLength(...);
        response.setBufferSize(...);
        response.getOutputStream().write(...);
    } finally {
        response.getOutputStream().close();
    }
}
```

then open your link using

```
target="_blank"
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the opening of a new page (in case of successful download, the page will close immediately and our clients may be scared  :) )

Comment: target="_self" ?

Comment: "_self" unfortunately will use the same page to display error. I will try with "framename". Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

Redirect to the same page can be an option. 
Keep in mind if you will refresh the page you will loose all the information in the page.
I am just saying in case this controller will be in charge of saving.

Comment: As you said, if I recall the same page, I will lose all informations in the page but I would like to preserve them.

Comment: You can use Ajax to avoid reloading or you can repopulate using model addattribute

Comment: Yes but with ajax I can't download the file. I'm not using model attribute because I'm populating datatable with some data that returns from web service. So I would like to avoid the "second" call. Thanks anyway