# Downloading a pdf file in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, pdf, download

Through `post` method in jquery I tried to download a pdf but it doesn't work. File is not getting downloaded. where am I doing wrong?

main.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </head>
<body>
    <script>
        function downloadpdf(){
            alert("working");
        $.post('download.php',{pdf:'Intro.pdf'},function(data){if(data=="y"){alert("Downloaded");}});
    }
        </script>
    <button onclick="downloadpdf();">download</button>   
</body>
</html>
```

download.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['pdf'])){
    $bbpdf=$_POST['pdf'];
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$bbpdf");
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($bbpdf));
readfile($bbpdf);
echo "y";
}
```

Comment: What happens and what do you expect to happen? "doesn't work" is quite a weak problem description.. :P

Comment: File is not getting downloaded . I want to download a pdf file.

Comment: Any errors? What does the js console say? One thing I can see right away is that `echo "y";` will add a `y` to the end of the file, which I'm going to guess is not intended. You only want to print out the data from the file.

Comment: No errors. Actually I tried in download.php `if(isset($_POST['pdf'])){echo "y";}` it worked fine. So, problem with `header` to download a pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="download.php?pdf=Intro.pdf">download</a>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_GET['pdf'])){
    $bbpdf = $_GET['pdf'];

    header("Pragma: public"); // required
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private", false); // required for certain browsers
    header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($bbpdf));
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($bbpdf));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($bbpdf);
}
```

Note: Don't use AJAX. There is no cross-browser way to force the browser to show a save-as dialog in JavaScript for some arbitrary blob of data received from the server via AJAX.

Comment: It works fine. So, Is there no way to download a file using the method which I posted?

Comment: You can use iframe. Check this link, if it can help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613526/php-file-download-using-post-data-via-jquery-ajax

Comment: I have a problem with this. Loading icon keeps on displaying.file is getting dowloaded but loading icon doesn't hide though page is loaded fully.`$(window).on('beforeunload', function(event) {
   $('#loading').show(); });
$(window).on('load', function(event) {
    $('#loading').hide();});`

Comment: `beforeunload` triggered though page is not unloaded