# Error PDF jhipster and jasper

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jasper-reports, jhipster

I want to send a report from "Spring" to the angular. I am using "jHipster" as the basis of my project. I'm using "OAuth2"

This is my java controller.

```
Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("jasperT/a3.jasper"), model, jasperDTO);
    System.out.println("Creo el jasperPrint");


    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
    String filename = "test.pdf";
    headers.setContentDispositionFormData("inline", filename);
    headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    System.out.println("Creo el RESPONSE");
    return response;
```

My service.

```
     angular.module('bbfacturacionserverwebApp').factory('TicketImprimir', function($resource) {
return $resource('api/tickets/imprimir/:id', {}, {
    'get': {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer'

    }

});
```

});

My angular controller.

```
     $scope.imprimir = function (id) {

    TicketImprimir.get({id: id}, function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        var file = new Blob([result], {type: 'application/pdf'});
        var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
       window.open(fileURL);

    });
};
```

Trying to open the PDF says "Error". This is the response.

curl 'http://localhost:8080/api/tickets/imprimir/526?cacheBuster=1447703356141' -H 'Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.1401749376.1447187427; NG_TRANSLATE_LANG_KEY=%22es%22' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,gl;q=0.4' -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxx' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, /' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:8080/' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --compressed

%PDF-1.4 %???? 3 0 obj <>stream p4??|?HW?$?рu&b?[?j??????l?,??dB$?XR0ic??@??T?"?8~;PY(?$E????d@c5?Py???"?}a?߿T??????N?x??w??????Γ?l?΀aCƠ ?ӅJ?uP??Fv??I?zj ?Юh??A?\?4\eE???A?>?? ??#R)?J??$9p@(?zP^Ep?Ez |?BQ?????F?r??>?*Bҩ@B?$?"˔?X4Q?s??vռ??:E???9VHʣB???N?????@???H??F+%h??Q*?<0*?J[???m w??ѐ;aG??(?t??K$?J???U???~@ ?{Qy???/?bD????jռ?Т?붟w???f|Zt͎?6l?(?·????~6PxA?r?ח??LV?j???eA??p??v?&?V?]4P2?ƅ"?G??Sd??e?(!?S??L?R????m??w_R???a??^R???"???`?(???tMŖ\t??>gεb??"?;=dG???^??3?/s?B endstream endobj 1 0 obj <>/Parent 4 0 R/Contents 3 0 R/Type/Page/Tabs/S/Resources<>/Font<>>>/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]/Rotate 90>> endobj 5 0 obj [1 0 R/XYZ 0 605 0] endobj 2 0 obj <> endobj 4 0 obj <> endobj 6 0 obj <> endobj 7 0 obj <> endobj 8 0 obj <>/Pages 4 0 R>> endobj 9 0 obj <> endobj xref 0 10 0000000000 65535 f 0000000754 00000 n 0000001040 00000 n 0000000015 00000 n 0000001128 00000 n 0000001005 00000 n 0000001191 00000 n 0000001245 00000 n 0000001277 00000 n 0000001380 00000 n trailer <<24fed746a4c8be3e57800ecb2cc9a4a7>]/Info 9 0 R/Size 10>> startxref 1547 %%EOF

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467747/properly-create-and-serve-pdf-blob-via-html5-file-and-url-apis, the log of the result starts %PDF-1.4 % correct?

Comment: and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628378/angularjs-display-blob-pdf-in-an-angular-app