# jquery ajax not serving pdf file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, pdf

I am trying to download a pdf file using jquery, ajax & django.

My django views.py:

```
if request.POST.get('action') == 'download_labels':
    order_list = json.loads(request.POST.get('order_dict'), None)
    PackedOrders(dbname, order_list).downloadLabels()
    file = open('shipping_labels.pdf','rb')
    response = HttpResponse(file, content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=shipping_labels.pdf"
    os.system('rm shipping_labels.pdf')
    return HttpResponse(response, content_type='application/pdf')
```

My ajax query:

```
data : {action:'download_labels',
        order_dict:JSON.stringify($checkedRows)},

success : function(response, status, request) {
    var file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
    window.open(fileURL,'_blank');
},
```

The ajax returns the file as binary data response and open it in a new tab. But all I see in new tab are blank pages. The number of blank pages is equal to number of pages in original pdf file.

In Console I see this:

```
Error: Invalid XRef stream header
...
Warning: Indexing all PDF objects
pdf.worker.js (line 235)
<System>
PDF 85b859244e496561d60d217869d5d38a [1.3 - / -] (PDF.js: 1.3.76)
Error: Bad FCHECK in flate stream: 120, 239
...
```

[Here](http://tempsend.com/ED0E040A5F/7BAE/console_log.txt) is the complete log file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a jQuery expert but I do not think jQuery ajax supports blobs. In the documentation it only lists these data types: xml, json, script, or html.
However I was able to get this functionality to work without using jQuery and  using ajax with plain JavaScript with this code,

My JavaScript (I would also add error handling to this)

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/pdf_test', true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';

xhr.onload = function(e) {
  if (this.status == 200) {
    var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type: 'application/pdf'}),
    fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(fileURL,'_blank');
  }
};

xhr.send();
```

My django view ( I would also add error handling to this)

```
def pdf_test(request):
    pdf_file = open(r'C:\Pdfs\calculation_of_semiconductor_failure_rates.pdf', 'rb')
    response = HttpResponse(pdf_file, content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="shippinglabels.pdf"'
    return response
```

On top of this if you don't need to open in new tab but can just download the file, then you can avoid ajax/Javascript entirely and just use HTML which is a simpler approach

`<a id="pdf-test" href="/pdf_test">Download PDF</a>`

For credit and further reading I used these links

[jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

[StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467747/properly-create-and-serve-pdf-blob-via-html5-file-and-url-apis)

[Introduction to JavaScript Blobs and File Interface](http://qnimate.com/an-introduction-to-javascript-blobs-and-file-interface/)