# how to process filepathresult at script returning from controller to download file

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Hi I have function at controller which return a `.rar` file .

```
public FilePathResult ExportAllToExcel(SearchPage searchpage) {
    return File(strpath + ".rar", " ", filename);
}
```

and I am calling this function using jQuery but not able to handle return value

```
$.post("@Url.Action("ExportAllToExcel")",values,function(data){
    ??...
});
```

how to process data to show downloaded file.

Comment: Do you want to use JavaScript to process the bytes of the file in some way, or just prompt the user to download the file?

Comment: prompt user to download the file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript/jquery to download file via POST with JSON data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499597/javascript-jquery-to-download-file-via-post-with-json-data)

Comment: I tried but The page is getting hang and that is not working in my case.