# PHP - Using CURL to authenticate and download a remote File

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to use php to post variables to another php on a remote server and on the file at the remote server I want to read the file and force its download. The file on the remote server is not on a public folder, that's why I need to call the file first, so it authenticates and get the protected file.

Everything works, but I don't get any file back.

At the remote PHP I'm using standards readfile and headers to download a file.

I think maybe the problem is with the CURL setup, I'm using the standard CURL calls is there any specific header or setup I need to use when I call CURL to have the file downloaded?

This is the CURL i'm using

```
$request = curl_init();
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_URL, $postURL);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($request);
curl_close($request);
```

Where $postFields contain the variables to authenticate and confirm the file on the other server.

On the other server the php after authenticating does the normal force download:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$newFileName.'"');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');

readfile($path);
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Hi, I believe I found the issue. The problem is that when I call through .$post on the jquery the local server php, the curl interrupts the ajax call

```
        $.post('local.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data){
            alert(data);
            }
        }, "json").fail(function() {
            alert('error');
        });
```

So I'll have to figure it out how to call through the jquery the local.php without breaking the process.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please add the relevant code you already have got (especially the curl initialization, even if it is not working). That way we can get a better understanding of what you want to achieve / where the problem is.

Comment: Hi @dhh I updated with the code. Thanks!

Comment: @Kitara, how are you getting `$newFileName` and `$path` variables? If you put a `print_r($response)`, what is the output?

Comment: Hi @DimasPante $newFileName is just a arbitrary name with the extension of the real file. And $path is the path to the file we want to be downloaded. I already put an output of php errors and php finds the file, the path is not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using basic HTTP authentication on the target site - you can add logon information by using the option `CURLOPT_USERPWD`.

```
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
```

**edit**: regarding the ajax call - jQuery will execute the `fail` method, if the server returns an error. Furthermore - you are specifying `json` as data-type in your ajax-call. The download will not return json, I think.

**edit 2**: I do not think that a download via `$.post` will be possible that way, as jQuery only knows one of `xml`, `html`, `script`, `json`, `jsonp`, `text`. You might try authenticating via your ajax request, have the ajax response return the download URL redirect the browser to that target. Or you could try using a hidden iframe for that download. Have a look at those posts ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499597/javascript-jquery-to-download-file-via-post-with-json-data) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499597/javascript-jquery-to-download-file-via-post-with-json-data/8394118#8394118)) - the issue is discussed in details here.

Comment: Hi @dhh please see my edit on the question. Thanks for your help. But it looks like I will have to change the process a little bit! Thank you!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your eidt. What would be the return type needed? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot and I believe is the right direction.