# Accessing a file farther back in the webpage filepath through HTML or Javascript, and downloading that file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, download, filepath

My website layout is two layers deep (~/Layer1/Layer2/index.html and data.csv)

My goal is that when a button on the HTML page is clicked, it triggers the jQuery function (that's working) that starts the download of the data.csv file.

I can't figure out how to 1) Access the data.csv file location from javascript/jQuery. and 2)Initiate a download instead of having the webpage open is as a webpage.

Thanks!

Comment: Technically if you open the .csv file in a new tabs it should download on its own

Comment: Yeah I would think that too, but all it does is open a new webapge with the location /Layer1/Layer2/data.csv instead of /Layer1/Layer2/index.html. I want it to stay on the index page and just download the file.

Comment: You could use an Iframe. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499597/javascript-jquery-to-download-file-via-post-with-json-data/3506018#3506018

Comment: @NicolasRacine — That's a **deleted** answer to a question asking how to trigger a download in response to an Ajax request. There's no Ajax involved here so no need to do anything so complicated.

Comment: Well. There's probably no Ajax involved. The question is missing anything resembling code. It isn't clear why jQuery is involved at all.

Comment: **Solved:** It must have been something with the file path. I changed the location of the csv file to the root folder of the website. I added an iframe in JS with the file path ../../Data.csv which worked. Thanks for the help everyone.