# Force download mp3 file from its cdn URL javascript

Tags: javascript, python

I am interested in downloading mp3 files from remote server (CDN) URL. Unfortunately it does not work when I simply put this URL as the "href" for a "button" or "a" HTML element; the file gets just open/streamed in new tab. How can I force downloading it using javascript ? or else if there is a python server-side based solution ?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript/jQuery to download file via POST with JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499597/javascript-jquery-to-download-file-via-post-with-json-data)

Answer (score 0):

If your remote server is of a different origin, this is not possible. See [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#downloading-resources). Your only options are:

1. Setting the `Content-Disposition` header of the CDN's responses to `attachment`
2. Changing the CORS policy of the CDN to allow downloading in JavaScript

If your remote server is of the same origin, the `download` attribute should do what you want:

```html
<a href="URL" download>text</a>
```